# UILongPressGestureRecognizer will not respond to touch & HOLD

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I am writing an Objective-C program for iPhone.

I am trying to implement a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and cannot get it to behave the way I want it to.

What I *want* to do is simple:

Respond to a touch being *held* down on the screen.

The `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` works just fine whenever the touch moves and when the touch begins but if I hold down the touch in the same place, nothing happens.

Why?

How can I handle a touch begining, not moving, and staying in the exact same place?

Here's my current code.

---

```
// Configure the press and hold gesture recognizer 
touchAndHoldRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(touchAndHold:)]; 
touchAndHoldRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.1; 
touchAndHoldRecognizer.allowableMovement = 600;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:touchAndHoldRecognizer];
```

Comment: // Configure the press and hold gesture recognizer
    touchAndHoldRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(touchAndHold:)];
    touchAndHoldRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.1;
    touchAndHoldRecognizer.allowableMovement = 600;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:touchAndHoldRecognizer];

Comment: My point exactly. You don't get repeated events if you don't move. That's what I'm trying to fix. Do you know of a method with which I -can- get repeated events if I don't move?

Comment: This should be reopened because if you look carefully at what at this question is asking, it's not asking "how do I do a long press gesture", but rather "now do I get notifications in the middle of a long press gesture, even though I'm not moving." This is not a duplicate of that other question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The behavior you describe, where your gesture recognizer does not receive further calls to your handler when you're not moving is the standard behavior. The `state` property for these gestures as you move are of type `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`, so it makes sense that if things haven't changed, your handler won't be called.

You could

- Upon call to your gesture recognizer with `state` of `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` start a repeating timer;
- Upon call to your gesture recognizer with `state` of `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled`, `UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed`, or `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` then `invalidate` and release the timer;
- Make sure the gesture recognizer method is saving whatever value you're looking for in some class property (e.g. the value of `locationInView` or whatever)

So, maybe something like:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint location;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.1;
    gesture.allowableMovement = 600;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (void)handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [self someMethod:self.location];
}

- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    self.location = [gesture locationInView:self.view];

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ||
             gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed ||
             gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }

    [self someMethod:self.location];
}

- (void)someMethod:(CGPoint)location
{
    // move whatever you wanted to do in the gesture handler here.

    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

@end
```

Comment: ... I think I'm starting to get it.  My problem was, I wasn't understanding Apple's methodology with how they deal with touches.  I think the reason why I spend 4 hours today scouring the internet for answers and getting increasingly frustrated is that I was missing the point. You helped me to see this Rob.  There's no method in Cocoa like "handleTouchesRemainedStationary" because if a touch hasn't ended, and hasn't moved...  Then __obviously__ it has remained the same. You can just continue iterating in your execution loop.  Thanks, Rob!

Comment: @J-Rock Cool. Your implementation might vary (you might, for example, reset the timer upon a gesture, so you don't get timer calls if you're moving), but you get the idea. FYI, I simplified my code a little.

Comment: @J-Rock And one final observation, which I alluded to earlier. If you want a continuous gesture that starts very quickly after you touch the screen and continues as you move around, you might want to use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. If that works for you, it makes more sense. Most programmers would be mislead by the use of a long press gesture recognizer that allows movement of 600 points. If you have to use long press for some reason (e.g., it's important to have that wait of 0.1 at the start), the use it, otherwise, consider `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: @Rob if you get a chance. I'm having issues with longpress gesture recognisers. Would there be a conflict if I have linked a long press recogniser to a pickerView? because I am getting crash reports in my didSelect method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46170876/random-crash-on-pickerview-didselect-cfrunloop-is-calling-out-to-a-source1-p?noredirect=1#comment79305779_46170876