# random crash on pickerview didSelect : __cfrunloop_is_calling_out_to_a_source1_perform1_function

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipickerview

I have received the following crash report but I do not understand the issue.Line 487 points to a check if the pickerView in the delegate is a particular variable.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  App                    0x1001c5208 specialized NewCorrectiveVC.pickerView(UIPickerView, didSelectRow : Int, inComponent : Int) -> () (NewCorrectiveVC.swift:487)
1  App                    0x1001c2028 @objc NewCorrectiveVC.pickerView(UIPickerView, didSelectRow : Int, inComponent : Int) -> () (NewCorrectiveVC.swift)
2  UIKit                  0x197a83154 -[UIPickerView _sendSelectionChangedForComponent:notify:] + 116
3  UIKit                  0x197a8338c -[UIPickerView _sendSelectionChangedFromTable:notify:] + 344
4  UIKit                  0x197fb0424 -[UIPickerTableView _scrollingFinished] + 188
5  UIKit                  0x197fb05fc -[UIPickerTableView scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:] + 28
6  UIKit                  0x197b216ac -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _scrollViewDidEndDeceleratingForDelegate] + 132
7  UIKit                  0x1979b6db0 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _stopScrollDecelerationNotify:] + 332
8  UIKit                  0x1979b68ec -[UIScrollView _smoothScrollWithUpdateTime:] + 2356
9  QuartzCore             0x194bc01bc CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch(unsigned long long) + 44
10 QuartzCore             0x194bc0068 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 444
11 IOKit                  0x191c27138 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 372
12 CoreFoundation         0x19195056c __CFMachPortPerform + 180
13 CoreFoundation         0x191968934 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
14 CoreFoundation         0x1919680e8 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436
15 CoreFoundation         0x191965bcc __CFRunLoopRun + 1840
16 CoreFoundation         0x191894048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
17 GraphicsServices       0x19331a198 GSEventRunModal + 180
18 UIKit                  0x1978792fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
19 UIKit                  0x197874034 UIApplicationMain + 208
20 App                    0x100173d04 main (AppDelegate.swift:22)
21 libdispatch.dylib      0x1908785b8 (Missing)
```

Code:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    if pickerView == assignedTo
    {
        if employees.count > 0 {
            selectedEmp =  employees[row].employeeId
        }
    }
    else if pickerView == category \\this is line 487
    {
        if categories.count > 0 {
            selectedCat = categories[row].wocategoryId
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Not sure if the following is relevant but I do have observers linked to my pickerViews:

```
let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPressed))
assignedTo.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
let catLongPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.catLongPressed))
category.addGestureRecognizer(catLongPressRecognizer)
self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
self.scroll.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```

FYI:

```
public func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

Comment: Could you please share what exception are you getting, that is more helpful for us.

Comment: @AshokPolu in crashlytics I see EXC_BREAKPOINT and then the snippet pasted above

Comment: put a break point at 487 line, debug the app, may be category is coming as nil.

Comment: comparing with `nil` is perfectly possible in swift @AshokPolu

Comment: @AshokPolu category is an IBOutlet pickerview. It is not nil after adding the breakpoint. I cannot reproduce the issue, but received a crash report on it

Comment: silly question, your crash is linked to your code current version?

Comment: @ReinierMelian crash is linked to the code above, yes

Comment: If this is in the field, it's optimized code. Don't place absolute faith in line numbers. I'd be as suspicious of the `employees[row]` and `categories[row]` calls, since those can cause this crash.

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks for the response, I'm confused as to how they could cause a crash as the pickerViews numberOfRowsInComponent is set to be equal to employees.count and categories.count respectively?

Comment: Having any part of this (modifying the arrays or calling UIKit methods) occur on a non-main thread is the most common cause. Another is changing the arrays without informing the picker view that things have changed (calling `reloadAllComponents` for instance). But see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is in the call to `==`.

```
if pickerView == assignedTo
```

This isn't really what you mean. This forces a call to the `==` function and tries to evaluate equality between these two objects. If one of them is `nil` that will crash.

`pickerView` should never be `nil`, but I've encountered cases where UIKit sends `nil` for parameters that should never be `nil`. (This especially can happen if there are any calls to UIKit methods on background threads. Be very careful about not doing that, but it can also happen due to UIKit bugs.)

`assignedTo` can be `nil` if the view hasn't loaded. In theory you should never get this call in that case, but again, it's possible in the presence of bugs, again most commonly due to calling UIKit methods off the main thread (any UIKit methods; it doesn't always have to be related to this particular picker view), but UIKit sometimes has bugs of its own.

In any case, you don't mean "is pickerView *equal* to assignedTo." You mean "is pickerView *exactly the same thing* as assignedTo." That's `===`:

```
if pickerView === assignedTo
```

`===` does a pointer comparison, so even in the face of an invalid `nil` it's safe.

Keep in mind that this is almost certainly related to a race condition. The fact that it doesn't easily reproduce when you run it in the debugger doesn't mean anything. It might happen once in 10k tries, only in Release, exclusively on iPhone 6. That's the nature of race conditions.

Comment: good to know Rob! I will make the change and update and hopefully that will solve the crashes

Comment: I'd still be on the lookout for calls to UIKit off the main thread or modifications to the arrays off the main thread. Those could still be the underlying cause of the problem (and the crash may still be on those subscript lines rather than the `if`). In Xcode9 you can turn on the Thread Sanitizer and it'll detect certain incorrect thread accesses.

Comment: Will double check all pickerview loads are wrapped in DispatchQueue.main.async {}

Comment: And also any modifications to the arrays. Also make sure that anything that modifies the array lengths reloads the picker (another very common mistake to miss that).